# GIT - How to see Commits that I've made

Tags: git, github

I nice command could be:

```
git commit -ls
```

I wanna see all commits that I did before push it to Remote.
I've tried `git diff` with its commands such `--cached` but it's not what I need now.

Comment: Thx @vcsjones "Unpushed" is the keyword for this search :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --author='your name registered with git within quotes'
```

example:

```
git log --author='Some Name'
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the commits in your version of master but not in origin's master is this

```
git log origin/master..master
```

I have also set up an alias for git log that makes a lot of this kind of info easier to see. You might want to give it a shot.

```
lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h%C(cyan)%d%Creset %s %C(white)- %an, %ar%Creset'
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I really appreciate that.